# In Catalina, how do I grant permissions to applications that haven't asked for them?

Tags: catalina, notifications, permission, dock

I used Fluid to create a Gmail app that would show my unread mail count in the dock.  After upgrading to Catalina, the app no longer shows a badge in the dock, and I believe this is because it doesn't have permission to do so.  But if I go into the Notification preferences, neither Fluid nor my Gmail app appear, so I can't grant them permission via the UI

I've reported this to the maintainer of Fluid, but while I wait, is there any other way for me to grant these permissions?  Perhaps there's some command I can run from the terminal, or a plist somewhere that I could edit, to grant my app permission to show badges on its icon?

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a canonical answer for this for all Catalina's restrictions.

Comment: There is a [github script](https://gist.github.com/talkingmoose/9faf50deaaefafa9a147e48ba39bb4b0) described in this article [How to Manage Catalina’s New Application Notifications with a Profile](https://mrmacintosh.com/how-to-manage-catalinas-new-application-notifications-with-a-profile/) (step 6) which will let you drag an app into the script and make a profile for your app on your desktop.  You can then apply it with double-click.  I don't know if it works with your app but you can always delete `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ncprefs.plist` to reset notification settings if not.

Comment: @benwiggy - and for this similar question [Add apps to “Files and Folders” permissions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376907/add-apps-to-files-and-folders-permissions) too..