# How to remove privacy settings for files and folders in Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, settings, privacy

It seems to be simple, but how to remove the given privacy settings for files and folders? I have some double mentions which I would like to remove!

[image]

So how to achieve this, when the `+ / -` control buttons are disabled?

Comment: `tccutil` can help a bit

Answer (score 1):

In short, those buttons don't work and there's no easy way of adding, deleting, or modifying the contents of that list.

For the difficult way, have a look at this answer:
[Add apps to "Files and Folders" permissions?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376907/add-apps-to-files-and-folders-permissions)

Comment: Okay, but why are they there?

Comment: Because Apple copied the interface elements from the "Full Disk Access" view, and forgot to remove them or hook them up to object methods.